# JPA 2 "member of" syntax doesn't work with members of superclass

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

Basically i have a named query "findServerWithNic" which refuses to work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vnm_server")
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name="findServerWithNic",
        query="SELECT s FROM Server s, Nic n "+
                "WHERE n.id = :nicId AND n member of s.nics"
    )
})
public class Server extends NetworkedDevice implements Serializable
{...}
```

nics is not defined in Server but in it's superclass NetworkedDevice:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vnm_networked_device")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "c_device_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class NetworkedDevice extends AbstractIdentifyable implements Serializable
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "connectedHost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "c_index")
    protected List<Nic> nics = new ArrayList<Nic>();

    public List<Nic> getNics() {
        return nics;
    }

    public void setNics(List<Nic> nics) {
        this.nics = nics;
    }
}
```

now i have a testcase that creates a Nic instances a adds it to a Server instance (s.getNics() contains the instance, i checked) but the invocation of the query

```
public Server findVirtualServerOfNic(Long nicId) {        
    final Server network = em.createNamedQuery("findServerWithNic", Server.class)
                                .setParameter("nicId", nicId)
                                    .getSingleResult();
    return network;
}
```

results in an NoResultException

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.throwNoResultException(EJBQueryImpl.java:1246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:750)
    at com.profitbricks.provisioning.vnm.jpa.impl.VNManagementJPAImpl.findVirtualServerOfNic(VNManagementJPAImpl.java:101)
```

originally the nics-member was private but even setting it to protected didn't work.
We use eclipselink 2.2.0-M4 as our JPA 2-provider. Is this an eclipselink bug or is the query wrong?

Comment: You can try to enable SQL logging and look at the resulting SQL (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)

Comment: Do you have a successful result with manual SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Did you commit or flush the transaction?  If you did not, then the database may not have the value (depending on your flush mode), so your query will not return anything.

Enable logging and include the SQL.  If the SQL correct?

"member of" is generaly old JPQL syntax, normally "join" is used now instead

"SELECT s FROM Server s join s.mics n WHERE n.id = :nicId "